# Cannot compile interface-based projection in spring

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I've got an entity:

```
@Entity
class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String firstname, lastname;
    private int age;

    public Person() {
    }
    //getters and setters
```

And a projection interface:

```
public interface NamesOnly {

    String getFirstname();
    String getLastname();
}
```

The methods names in projection are exactly the same as getters in the entity class.

My repository:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {

    List<NamesOnly> findAll();   
}
```

I can't compile it.

```
test/projectiontest/PersonRepository.java:[20,21] findAll() in test.projectiontest.PersonRepository clashes with findAll() in org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository
return type java.util.List<test.projectiontest.projection.NamesOnly> is not compatible with java.util.List<test.projectiontest.Person>
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#projections

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are using `findAll` which is already defined in the `CrudRepository` with a specific signature. Yours doesn't match that. You need another method name.

Comment: @M.Deinum ok, eg `List<NamesOnly> findById(Long id);` works fine, but how to implement `findAll` with the projection interface?

Comment: Define a custom method...

Answer (score 0):

Well, as @M.Deinum has mentioned in the comments, I can't use `findAll`, because it is already defined in `JpaRepository`. 
Instead of using projection interface I wrote the DTO class:

```
public class NamesOnlyDto {

    private String firstname, lastname;

    public NamesOnlyDto(String firstname, String lastname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }    
}
```

Then I could use it in my repository like this:

```
@Query("SELECT new test.projectiontest.projection.NamesOnlyDto(p.firstname, p.lastname) FROM Person p")
List<NamesOnlyDto> findEveryone();
```

It works fine. I'm pretty sure this is a workaround and there is a way to solve this with projection interface, so I leave this question unanswared. I hope someone else provide a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FindAllProjectedBy()` instead of `findAll()`